# Group by Having clause and check whether the values are same

Tags: sql, oracle, hive

I have a table like below.

```
Site  |   VSID1 |  VSID2 | Status
C1    |    0.1  |  1     |  Rejected
C1    |    0.1  |  1     |  Agreed
C1    |    0.2  |  2     |  Rejected
C1    |    0.2  |  2     |  Rejected
```

I want to get the result in a query and want all the records which are unique and with the same status e.g.  group by (site, VSID1, VSID2) and select the record, check to see if all the rows status is 'Rejected'

The answer should be the second set of records. The first set of records shouldn't be selected since it has rejected and agreed. The second set, on the other hand, should be selected as both are rejected.

Any help, much appreciated.

I tried with having (instr(status, 'Rejected')  > 1

Comment: Apologies, if the question misled anyone. If you see in the table there are two sets of records (group by site,vdid1,vdid2), first record has "rejected" status,  considering as a group; that record has two status(rejected, agreed), which is different. I wanted to select the group of records (which is the second one)  where the status should be same. in this case it is "rejected", both the records. I need the group of records where the status must be same. e.g. rejected

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
select Site ,VSID1 , VSID2 , Status
group by Site ,VSID1 , VSID2 , Status
having sum(case when status='Rejected' then 0 else 1 end)=0
```

OR Correlatd subquery

```
select * from tablename a where not exists (select 1 from tablename b where a.Site
=b.site and a.VSID1=b.VSID1  and a.VSID2=b.VSID2 where status<>'Rejected')
```

Comment: Thanks fa06. But your first query is picking up the first row as well as it matches the condition. I basically need to select all the records where for a given group (site,vsid1,vdid2) all the records status should be rejected. If you see the first set of records one rejected and one agreed, so it shouldnt select the records.

Answer (score 1):

With max and min:

```
select Site, VSID1, VSID2, min(Status) Status
from tablename 
group by Site ,VSID1 , VSID2
having min(Status)='Rejected' and max(Status)='Rejected'
```

If you want all the rows from the table:

```
select t.* from tablename t inner join (
    select Site, VSID1, VSID2
    from tablename 
    group by Site ,VSID1 , VSID2
    having min(Status)='Rejected' and max(Status)='Rejected'
) tt
inner join tt.Site = t.Site and tt.VSID1 = t.VSID1  and tt.VSID2 = t.VSID2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT site, VSID1, VSID2, max(Status)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY site, VSID1, VSID2
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Status) = 1
```

`max(Status)` might not look good but it does the trick for you if you need the `Status` to be in the output.